# What are Web Session and Viewstate equivalent objects in Windows Mobile

Tags: windows, mobile

Okay firstly I'm a newbie to mobile development, so I start out building an application, implement usercontrols for tabbed navigation and have requirement of passing data between these usercontrols and that had me in kind of a fix. So am currently looking for session or viewstate equivalent objects to store data and pass it between these usercontrols. If it helps, both usercontrols are loaded in the same form and are implementing search and display functionality each. Development environment is for windows mobile 6.

Answer (score 0):

Okay , so i solved it. Did not find equivalent objects but did find a simpler solution which involved creating my 2 pages as forms and passing data as properties in these 2 forms. Hope this helps someone